# An array converting to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following code, which returns an array:

```
const authorsName = [];
this.props.authors.map((e) => authorsName.push(e.name + ' ' + e.surname));
console.log(authorsName)
// ["Jonh Snow", "Jonh Rain"]
```

But when I try to send this array using the following code:

```
const s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.innerHTML = `window.customConfig.push({
   page_type: "article",
   article_authors: "${authorsName}"
})`;
```

the `authorsName` array turns into the next string:

```
article_authors: "Jonh Snow,Jonh Rain",
```

I do not understand why this is happening. Please, can you tellme what is the problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to desired output to look like? If you want it to be a string with space separating then you need to join the array with a space delimiter. Although if that is the desired outcome, you could just build up a string, and then pass that into article_authors instead of the array. Also it is rendering like that because you are using string literal.

Comment: Change to `article_authors: ${JSON.stringify(authorsName)}`, though, why build out the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the usage of [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that way works, but it is not quite correct. Remember that `.map()` returns a new array where each element is derived in some way from the original one, and do not mutates the original array. So, it will be better if you do something like next:

```
const authorsName = this.props.authors.map(e => e.name + ' ' + e.surname);
```

The other option, to keep the code more similar to the one you give, is to use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in this way:

```
const authorsName = [];
this.props.authors.forEach(e => authorsName.push(e.name + ' ' + e.surname));
```

Now, on your next code:

```
s.innerHTML = `window.customConfig.push({
    page_type: "article",
    article_authors: "${authorsName}"
})`;
```

the `authorsName` array is coerced to a string using the [Array.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method and the `MDN` says next about it:

> For Array objects, the `toString` method joins the array and **returns one string containing each array element separated by commas**. JavaScript calls the `toString` method **automatically** when an array **is to be represented as a text value** or when an array is referred to in a string concatenation.

So, instead you need to use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the array into a `JSON` representation of it.

```
s.innerHTML = `window.customConfig.push({
    page_type: "article",
    article_authors: "${JSON.stringify(authorsName)}"
})`;
```

You can check the difference between using `toString()` and `JSON.stringify()` on the next example:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];

console.log("With toString() =>", arr.toString());
console.log("With JSON.stringify() =>", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`article_authors` is being interpolated into a string, even though it's an array.

If you want the string as in your first snippet, try this instead:

```
const authors = [
{name: "Jonh",
 surname: "Snow"},
 {name: "Jonh",
 surname: "Rain"}
]
const authorsName = [];
const output = authors.map((e)=> authorsName.push(e.name + ' ' + e.surname));
console.log(authorsName)
const s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.innerHTML = `
   window.customConfig.push({
   page_type: "article",
   article_authors: "${JSON.stringify(authorsName)}"
   })
               `;

console.log(s.innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include an object in a string the toString method is called to make a string out of it. The toString method on array comma concatinates the content of the array.

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4].toString());
```

If you want a different format you can call join on the array to join the elements with a different sequence.

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4].join(', '));

console.log([1,2,3,4].join(' / '));

console.log([1,2,3,4].join(' - '));
```